# Let user cancel an installation in progress in NSIS

Tags: nsis

Using an NSIS built package, when it gets to the point of writing the files and doing the actual install procedure, the 'Cancel' button is grayed out and can't be used. How can I reactivate this button so users can cancel out of the install during this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real support for this, search the nsis forum for workarounds/hacks. You can begin here:

http://forums.winamp.com/forumdisplay.php?forumid=65

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Brief explanation given here.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/InstFiles_Cancel_-_Allowing_a_user_to_cancel_installation_during_InstFiles